# QStyle:: StandardPixmap does have an add/delete icon. Or plus/minus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, qstyle

I want to add an icon for add/delete from a list. Using like plus/minus icons

I just want to make sure that the built in icons in Qt. Found in StandardPixmap does not include this one for plus minus so I can add one myself using resources.

Anyone previously checked also?

Comment: Why don't you check what icons QStyle has? You can implement a simple script that allows you to know all the icons: https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/list-of-qt-icons/

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but could you use unicode characters instead? `U+002D` and `U+002B` for example

Comment: But this one just diplay the icons given in the list icons @eyllanesc

Comment: @Aditya OK i'll try.

Comment: @eyllanesc got your idea  now I guess, i'll see also thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trying quite same script as mentionned by @eyllanesc, for icons as available in here for qt-5  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum , no plus/minus icons are found.